# Outline Mesh Unity 2D

Tags: unity, 2d, mesh

I have a procedurally generated mesh in Unity and I was hoping to outline the edges of it. I've got a small shader for an outline but instead of it working around the edge the mesh ends up filled with the colour of the outline.

[image: Image of in game mesh]

I'm trying to get to something more like the scene red "selection outline":
[image: Image of scene outline in unity]

Is it even possible to outline a mesh the way I want to?

The shader is just a fresnel effect on the alpha channel:
[image: Image of fresnel effect in shader graph]

Material for mesh:

[image: Image of shader being used with material]

I would just outline the grid if it were square, but it can contain missing pieces:
[image]

Comment: "I've got a small shader for an outline" — show us the shader if you want help fixing the bug in it. But if your mesh is just a collection of squares, it might be easier to just generate a line renderer whose points are the perimeter of the shape, which your generation function should be able to produce while it's building the mesh.

Comment: @DMGregory, sorry, I've updated the question with some additional details, the shader is a fresnel effect on an alpha channel and it looks right in the materials panel. I would outline with a line renderer but it contains missing pieces sometimes.

Comment: That's not an outline shader, that's a Fresnel effect — these are different things. Fresnel helps highlight the edges of a smoothly curving 3D model as it bends away from the viewer (like the sphere in the material preview does). That's not something your mesh does, so it's obviously not appropriate here, and you should select a different outlining strategy. The LineRenderer approach can work with missing pieces, you just instantiate one line for each perimeter you want to trace.